# Uploading Files Using php and show as a webpage with help of msql and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have 3 simple files **index.php, upload.php, test123.php** and I want to upload the **JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF** to this directory test123.php/$file-id with the help of my sql and htaccess. But i have no idea about syntax.

**For better understanding** [see the video](https://streamable.com/jdltk0)

Here is my code

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select Image File to Upload:
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
  <hr>
  <?php
  include 'config.php';
  $query = $db->query("SELECT file_name FROM images ORDER BY uploaded_on DESC");
  if($query->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
          $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"];
  ?>
      <img src="<?= $imageURL; ?>" />
  <?php }} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```php
<?php
include 'config.php';
$statusMsg = '';
$backlink = ' <a href="./">Go back</a>';
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$user_image = $_FILES['file'];
$extension_array = explode(".", $user_image['name']);
$extension = end($extension_array);
$fileName = uniqid(true).".".$extension;

$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    if (!file_exists($targetFilePath)) {
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
                if($insert){
                    $statusMsg = "The file <b>".$fileName. "</b> has been uploaded successfully." . $backlink;
                }else{
                    $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again." . $backlink;
                } 
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." . $backlink;
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload." . $backlink;
        }
    }else{
            $statusMsg = "The file <b>".$fileName. "</b> is already exist." . $backlink;
        }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.' . $backlink;
}
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

test123.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>noreply</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>


  <?php
  include 'config.php';
  $id = (isset($_GET["img"])) ? $_GET["img"] : null;
  if($id !== null) {
    //you do your query, with prepared statement mind you :p
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from images where id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(["id"=>$id]);
    $image = $stmt->fetch();
    if($image) {
      //do things
    }
    else {
      //not found, throw a 404 error or something
    }
  }
  else {
    //no id, throw a 403 for example
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I just start the programming and my teacher said if you stuck any problem ask the stackoverflow community they helped thousand's of people to writing a better & understandable code.
I really appreciate if someone tell the exact syntax.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Have you checked out some ofthe several other questions here on SO that deal with file uploads in a php-mysql environment?

Comment: actually the code is perfect but i want .htaccess code that uploads the file to the database regarding this url structure test123.php/$file-name

Comment: please check this out For better understanding https://streamable.com/jdltk0

Comment: .htaccess does not upload anything to anywhere. Pls clarify your question!

Comment: ok i want to upload jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf these types of files and show as a webpage 
like i upload a picture, the image name is demo.jpg and then save to the database and show as domain.com/test123.php/$file-name. have you get my point

Comment: So, it this question just about how to use pretty urls and transform those into get parameters that you can use in php? In this case your question has nothing to do with php or mysql, it is pure .htaccess and such questions have already been answered here on SO.

Comment: yeah, but i want to change  the image-id to image-name,
check please


ReWriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test123/(.*)$ /test123.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: i want to change test123.php/?id=1 to test123.php/$file_name. can you tell me what is 
the exact rewrite rule